# How to remove the little bird icon in Concrete5 Tweetcrete

Tags: css, twitter, concrete5

Recently someone has asked me to solve a little problem on a website of theirs, but I can't really figure out where it comes from. The site uses Concrete5 with Tweetcrete installed, and I use a tweetcrete block to display tweets, both on the homepage and on a dedicated social media page. In all the blocks though, the tweets are displayed with a little bird icon attached, which doesn't work well when the window is resized - it obscures the text. I cannot find where that icon coms from though, there doesn't seem to be anything in that block that causes it. There is nothing special about the code either, no styles.

To see the the problem, visit [the homepage](http://www.schoonbroabant.nl/).
It'll be on the right hand side, towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it via CSS like so:

```
.ccm-tweetcrete-timeline ul li {
    background-image:none;
}
```